# Why is there a small part of the distribution map on the right side and how do I fix it using sf package in R?

Tags: r, maps, r-sf

I am trying to create a distribution map on North America. But a small part of the map is on the right side of the plot. The result is like in the screenshot.

Screenshot of the map:
[image: Screenshot of the map]

I tried it with sf package to put them together but somehow I could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On addition to @jindra-lacko's answer, you can use a specific [projection suitable for contiguous US and Alaska](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457636/what-is-the-right-epsg-crs-code-for-the-united-states). So no need to crop your object:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tigris)
#> To enable caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)`
#> in your R script or .Rprofile.
library(ggplot2)

# the one & only USA 
states <- states() %>% 
  filter(!STUSPS %in% c('MP', 'VI', 'PR', 'GU', 'AS')) 

ggplot(data = states) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
# Change CRS

states_epsg <- st_transform(states, "ESRI:102008")


ggplot(data = states_epsg) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is [Attu island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attu_Island) of WWII fame. It is the westernmost island of the Aleutian archipelago, and lies west of the dateline / antimeridian.

To fix it - or rather to "fix" it, since in truth it is mapped *exactly* where it should be - you would need to crop the data to the western hemisphere.

For an example consider this piece of code that reproduces the unwanted behaviour of Aleutian archipelago:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tigris)
library(ggplot2)

# the one & only USA 
states <- states() %>% 
  filter(!STUSPS %in% c('MP', 'VI', 'PR', 'GU', 'AS')) # not really states sensu stricto

ggplot(data = states) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image: ill behaved USA]

```r
sf_use_s2(F) # to avoid cropping along great circles

cropped_states <- states %>% 
  sf::st_crop(c(xmin = -180, xmax = 0, ymin = 0, ymax = 180))

ggplot(data = cropped_states) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image: much better than before]